# How to save oneself from hell?

Tags: naraka, hell

How can one save oneself from going to hell ? What are the ways from which one can save himself from hell ?

Comment: Think of God. "As you think so you become"

Answer (score 3):

Here are some generalized guidelines from the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa, which discuss ways to avoid the pangs of hell.

> [Chapter 227](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502206.html) - Means to Save One from Tortures in Hells,
> Tīrtha-māhātmya, Nāgara-khaṇḍa
>
> Yudhiṣṭhira said:
>
> > 1. Fear has gripped me after listening to the description of the Narakas. O king, how can even those persons be liberated who have
> >    committed sins? Is it through Vratas, observances of restraints, Homas
> >    or by resorting to holy centres and shrines?
>
> Bhīṣma said:
>
> > 2. **If bones of the men are cast into Gaṅgā the Naraka (hellish) fire is incapable of adversely affecting those people remaining in between
> >    (dead but not having attained the final results of Karmas).**
>
> > 3. **If Śrāddha is performed in Gaṅgā by the sons (and descendants in their name,) those ancestors go beyond the Naraka, after being seated
> >    in an aerial chariot.**
>
> > 4. **After committing a sin, O king, if the people perform expiatory rites as laid down or make gifts of gold, they will not fall into
> >    Naraka.**
>
> > 5. The remaining ones attain Svarga or Naraka in accordance with their Karma, O king.
>
> > 6. Those who die in front of their master in Dhārātīrtha (holy Tīrtha in the form of battle) (i.e. those who die in battle on behalf of
> >    their king) attain the greatest goal far beyond Naraka.
>
> > 7. He who casts off his body in Vārāṇasī, Kurukṣetra, Naimiṣa, Nāgarapura (i.e. Vadnagara), Prayāga or Prabhāsa will never see Naraka
> >    even if he has incurred Mahāpātakas (great sins).
>
> > 8. If one’s own son performs the rite of Utsarga (dedicatory release) of a dark bull along with the celebration of its marriage with a
> >    heifer, he will never see Naraka even if he happens to be a
> >    Brāhmaṇa-slayer.
>
> > 9. After adopting Prāyopaveśana (religious fast unto death) with due meditation on Janārdana, if a person casts off his life, he never sees
> >    Naraka.
>
> > 10. Those who perform Prāyopaveśana in the holy shrine Citreśvara will never fall into Naraka.
>
> > 11. He who serves food in time or out of time to the distressed, the blind and the miserable while they are going on a pilgrimage and are
> >     excessively fatigued on the way, never sees a hell.
>
> > 12. He who makes the gift of Jaladhenu (water in the shape of a cow’s mouth) when the Sun is in Taurus or Tiladhenu (gingelly seeds in the
> >     shape of a cow) when the Sun is in Capricorn never sees Naraka.
>
> > 13. By viewing Somanātha on a Monday or at the time of lunar eclipse and by taking the holy dip in the ocean or in Sarasvatī, one never
> >     goes to hell.
>
> > 14. He who takes his holy bath in river Sannihiti in Kurukṣetra on a Sunday when there is solar eclipse (when Rāhu swallows the Sun),
> >     never sees Naraka.
>
> > 15. He who silently circumambulates Tripuṣkara on Full-Moon day in the month of Kārttika when the constellation is Kṛttikā, never sees
> >     Naraka.
>
> > 16. Those who view Caṇḍīśa at the time of the transit of the Sun into Capricorn on a Sunday, never fall into hell.
>
> > 17. O king, **those who save a cow from quagmire, a Brāhmaṇa lady from slavery, good people from a thief, a Brāhmaṇa from murder, never fall
> >     into hell.**
>
> > 18. Thus, O king, everything I was asked has been narrated to you, viz. How a man falls into hell even if he commits a minor sin and how
> >     he avoids falling therein by means of his (good) activities.
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare.

So basically we may summarize some ways to  save oneself from hells, as per the Skanda Purāṇa, as follows -

- Performing acts of peity like charity, penance, vrata, fasts, homa, etc.
- Saving cows, Brahminas, and the weak.
- Visiting sacred places and taking bath in sacred rivers during special festivities or tithis.
- Righteous conduct conducive to one's varnaashrama dharma. For instance - a Kshatriya dying in a battle field attains Heaven, since he followed his dharma.
- After death rituals being duly performed for the deceased by his sons, etc.
- Casting one's body in sacred cities /towns or tirthas.
- If a sin is committed, then if expiations are duly done for it as laid down in the Shastras, then that sin will nullify and hell maybe avoided.

Comment: Nice answer. If you want, you can also add about the seven cities giving moksha. Ultimately, one is saved from hell if moksha is given to that person. :)

Comment: Well, that's more or less, covered in Verse 7, above, even though indirectly! so @LSSJBroly :)